# Pop operation of stack implementation not working as expected

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I am JAVA n00b. I am trying to implement a stack data structure in Java. The algorithms of push, peek and display are working fine. The `pop` algorithm is not working as expected:

```
public int pop() {
    int temp;
    if(isEmpty())
        return -1;
    else {
        temp = arr[topElem];
        topElem--; // points to the top most element in the stack
        count--;   // keeps track of the total number of elements in the stack
        return temp;
    }
}
```

The `case` in `switch` statement for this algorithm is as follows:-

```
case 2:
    if(st.pop()==-1)
        System.out.println("The stack is empty.");
    else
        System.out.printf("The element popped is %d\n",st.pop());
    break;
```

If the elements entered are ( in that order ):-  1 2 4
Then at the first call to `pop`, 2 is popped and then only 1 remains in the stack. I am able to understand what might be wrong but can't pinpoint it in the code.

Comment: Return `-1` as indicater that the stack is empty is no good idea, what if you want to put the int `-1` on the stack? better throw an Exception, of `pop()` is called on an empty stack.

Comment: You're calling pop twice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `pop` twice (once in `st.pop() == -1`, and once in the `printf`).

You should change your code to something like:

```
int value = st.pop();
if (value == -1)
   System.out.println("The stack is empty.");
else
   System.out.printf("The element popped is %d\n", value);
```

Comment: I was thinking that this might be a problem but didn't have the conviction to actually try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you're calling pop twice.

the first is:

```
if(st.pop()==-1)
       System.out.println("The stack is empty.");
```

and the second is :

```
System.out.printf("The element popped is %d\n",st.pop());
```

you can use a variable to store the value of `st.pop()` and then check the value of the variable. next to write some logic code.